# Calculate $\int_0^1 \Big( \int _0^x \sqrt{y^2+\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{y^4}{x^4}} dy \Big) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Calculate $\int_0^1 \Big( \int _0^x \sqrt{y^2+\frac{y^2}{x^2}+\frac{y^4}{x^4}} dy \Big) dx$

I have a problem with this task because I have no idea what parametrization should be used to calculate it. I tried $x=r\sin \alpha, y=r \cos \alpha$ or $s=y, t=\frac yx$ or $s=y, t=(\frac yx)^2$ but in each case I got too complicated calculations.

Does anyone have any clever ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Substitute $y=xt$ in the inner integral; you get $$\int_0^1\int_0^1xt\sqrt{1+x^2+t^2}\,dt\,dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1x(1+x^2+t^2)^{3/2}\Bigg|_{t=0}^{t=1}\,dx\\=\frac{1}{15}\big((2+x^2)^{5/2}-(1+x^2)^{5/2}\big)\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=1}=\frac{9\sqrt3-8\sqrt2+1}{15}.$$

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by too complicated? Upon substitution $y=x\sqrt{z}$ the integral becomes $$\int_0^1 {\rm d}x \frac{x}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{x^2+z+1} \, {\rm d}z = \int_0^1 {\rm d}x \frac{x}{3} \left[ \left( x^2 + 2 \right)^{3/2} - \left(x^2+1\right)^{3/2} \right] \\
\stackrel{t=x^2}{=} \frac{1}{6} \int_0^1 {\rm d}t \left[ (t+2)^{3/2} - (t+1)^{3/2} \right] = \frac{1}{15} - \frac{8\sqrt{2}}{15} + \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{5}\, .$$

Comment: What is not complicated for you may be for OP; let's not be too facetious. +1 btw